# Parity of an encrypted key

Tags: keys, 3des

Does encrypting a double-length 3DES application key (that has an odd parity) under a double-length 3DES zone master key (also with an odd parity) affect the parity of the application key?

Answer (score 3):

No it does not affect the parity bits.

The plaintext or ciphertext doesn't have any parity bits specified. The application key is just a input to the cipher, which is a Pseudo Random Permutation. Permutation means a 1:1 mapping from plaintext - including parity bits - to the ciphertext. If you perform the permutation in the opposite direction the plaintext - again including the parity bits - will be restored.

The same goes if the master key is used within a specific mode of operation for the block cipher; the 1:1 relationship between plaintext and ciphertext will be maintained.

Note that as the ciphertext doesn't have any parity bits, the parity of the ciphertext is completely random; the parity of the plaintext is not mirrored in the parity of the ciphertext in any way. That also means that if you perform *key derivation* with the master key that you need to explicitly set the parity afterwards.

Note that some libraries do not actually validate the parity bits. It's better to set them none-the-less.

Comment: Added a note about key derivation and validation of parity bits for completeness. Those remarks may not be applicable for your particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

***YES***, *encryption* of a double-length 3DES application key with odd parity ***DOES*** affects the parity of the *result*; when using ECB, or other modes such as CBC with implicit or out-of-band IV (as common in 3DES key management), the cryptogram will not have odd parity, and thus can't pass as a 3DES application key with odd parity (with excellent but not overwhelming odds, about $1-2^{-16}\approx 99.9985\%$). Than makes it unlikely to accidentally use the encrypted key as a plain key; *if* the parity of the plain key is checked, of course.

---

*Encryption then decryption* of a double-length 3DES application key with odd parity will leave the key unchanged, including odd parity.

*Encryption then parity adjustment then decryption* of a double-length 3DES application key with odd parity (such that the result after parity adjustment can pass as a 3DES application key with odd parity) would give something with incorrect parity and leading to incorrect results if used (with excellent but not overwhelming odds), and with no discernible relation to the initial key (with good odds, about $1-2^{-7}\approx 99.2\%$).

Comment: Heh, answering with No or Yes depends on if you consider the decrypted key or the ciphertext itself. I answer No, you answer Yes and both are correct :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Indeed. My second paragraph is about what you consider in [your answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30039/555).